# On my iPhone I can't give my apps access to the camera, microphone, etc

Tags: iphone, ios, permission, bug

iOS Version: 11.3

My iPhone won’t allow me to give any apps camera, microphone, or library access.

I’ve gone to their individual settings for the apps and there’s no options. If I go to **Camera** in privacy, I don't see the options.

Furthermore, I notice all of my contacts are gone. None have any names nor can I give them any. If I try going to the Phone app, the tab for contacts has disappeared too!

In the Calendar, the option to add dates is grayed out and all the dates of the automatic holidays and such are gone too.

I’ve had the phone for just over a year and it only just started doing this.

I’ve made sure that I don’t have restrictions on, I’ve reset locations and permissions, and I’ve reinstalled apps. I really don’t know what else to do.

**How else might I try to resolve this?**

[image] [image]

Comment: is the iPhone jailbroken?  Are you using iCloud to backup your data?  Are you signed in to iCloud with the correct user ID and password?  If so, when you go to icloud.com do you see all your contacts and calendars?  Please [edit] your question to include your iOS version.

Comment: No it isn’t jailbroken, and I’m not using iCloud so I can’t check. But I just checked the actual contacts app and my contacts are there with their numbers and names, but I don’t have that tab in my phone app, and my text messages are just phone numbers still.

Comment: Usually, issues like this don't just start happening for no reason so something caused this.  Honestly, I have no idea what the issue is and hopefully someone else here does.  If you don't have a backup of your contact/calendar you might have not get it back if you have to reinstall.

Comment: That’s why I think it’s strange; I don’t do anything dodgy, so I assumed it to be a bug. But, I don’t know, maybe I’ve accidentally clicked on an ad, not thought anything of it, and somehow gotten something malicious there.

Comment: Thank you for your time and help, though. :)

Comment: Have you ever figured this out? I'm having the same issue

Comment: Sadly, no, I haven't; the phone is still like that. I just gave up since Apple is so locked down that any diagnosis is impossible. Sorry

Comment: I have been having this problem for a month now in Aug 21, starting out of nowhere or perhaps after declining some Siri activation questions. In the end this "Reset Location and Privacy" from [below](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/326105/432703) plus a restart helped. I did not test just a restart before.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes a simple reboot, or even a forced reboot may work. If not, try going to `Settings > General > Reset > Reset Location and Privacy` and see if this fixes the problem.

*Information extracted from [Digital Zen](http://www.digitalzenway.com/fix-it-when-iphone-wont-allow-apps-access-to-your-photos/). Additional information on this page, too.*

Comment: It’s been through many reboots and force reboots; I’ve had this problem for months now as I originally asked on the official Apple forums and got no response. I have tried resetting location and privacy to no avail, but it can’t hurt to try again so I’ll give it another shot. Thank you :)

Comment: Sadly, it didn’t do anything. Thank you though

Comment: it is working if do reset. but, apple will reject application if not ask permissions . Then , How to do the same

Comment: I have been having this problem for a month now in Aug 21, starting out of nowhere or perhaps after declining some Siri activation questions. In the end this "Reset Location and Privacy" plus a restart helped. I did not test just a restart before.

Comment: @Blama The only fix I've found for this is resetting the device. Try backing up your device to iTunes, then reset your device, and then sync your backup onto the reset device.

Comment: @Jack As I said - resetting Privacy settings already worked for me. But thanks anyway, found that answer via your question.